# Составление запроса(Django orm)

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Есть модели: `User`, `Project`, `News`.

`User` связан с `Project` связью многие ко многим(subscriptions).

`News` связан с проектом один ко многим.

Не могу составить запрос, в котором нужно получить все новости со всех проектов, на которые подписан пользователь и отсортировать их по времени.

Comment: Пожалуйста, выложите код с описанием моделей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Погадаем на кофейной гуще:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyFiled(Project)
    ...


class News(models.Model):
    ...
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    some_time_field = models.TimeField()
    ...
```

Предположим, `user` - искомый пользователь, полученный из запроса в нашем view. Тогда, все новости, относящиеся к проектам, на которые подписан пользователь, получаются как-то так:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user
...

def some_view(request):
    user = get_user(request)
    user_subscriptions = user.subscriptions.all()
    news_from_subscriptions = News.objects.\
        filter(project__in=user_subscriptions).\
        order_by('-some_time_field')
...
```

Правильно ли я угадал вашу модель данных и желаемое направление сортировки? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял структуру, можно составить такой запрос:
`Project.objects.filter(user=current_user).prefetch_related('news')`

У каждого объекта `queryset` будет атрибут `news` со со списком новостей.   Чтобы ответить более нужно видеть код моделей.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

Select user.* Where user.ProjectID IN (
Select Project.id from Project Where Project.id = &NewsProjectID
)

Смысл должен быть понятен.

Comment: штука в том,что мне нужно сделать запрос на Django ORM,а не просто sql....с помощью sql было бы проще

Comment: @DenisTimofeev NB: если вы затрудняетесь с ORM или запрос кажется вам неоптимальным, всегда можно использовать метод raw(), в который передавать SQL-запрос в чистом виде (к сути вопроса не относится, но вдруг когда-нибудь пригодится)